# Can't acces my listview from my async task

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to build an async task that fills a list view. When I try and to set my listView with findViewBYId with:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) ((View) c).findViewById(R.id.tastelist);
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot cast from Context to View
```

My whole async task class is:

```
public class GetTasteJSON extends AsyncTask
<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;

    public GetTasteJSON(Context context)
    {
         c = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        //decode json here
        try{

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((View) c).findViewById(R.id.tastelist);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<BeerData> beerList = new ArrayList<BeerData>();

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is in the line that says `((View) c).findViewById(R.id.tasteList)`. Your parentheses say to cast the context c to a View. Maybe try `((ListView) c.findViewById(R.id.tasteList))`

Comment: yes and when I just to c.finViewById eclipse tells me to cast it to a view...

Comment: Right. I edited my comment. I think Eclipse is adding the cast in the wrong place. You should only need those extra parentheses around the ListView cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the casting to

```
ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.tastelist);
```

The context in this case should be your Activity

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between calling findViewById from and activity (in this case context) and a View (which I believe you are trying to do). If the view you have inflated to start the activity is a parent of the view you want to obtain that you may want to try to cast to your activity, not a view. Otherwise try to create an instance variable of type ViewGroup and pass in the parent view with a setter.

Comment: I don't think he inflated his layout.. He casted it to View just because Eclipse suggested it.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right (I did not see the comments while responding to the question). I agree that a cast to Activity is the solution. Perhaps a cast can be avoided with an Activity instance variable instead of a Context instance variable (I say this without knowing the rest of the code)

Answer (score 0):

The context have to be your activity so cast it to your  Activity and not to a View like you did...

In case you have a List Activity you just have to do it like this:

```
ListView lv=((ListActivity) context).getListView();
```